# ts-jest and monorepo baseUrl module resolution not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm moving my project to monorepo using npm workspaces, and I'm having problems with configuration jest and ts-jest, my client side has a "baseUrl" option of "./src" in the tsconfig, and I can't seem to make ts-jest being able to import modules based on it, I really tried all of the options of `modulePaths` and `moduleDirectories` like they suggest in the troubleshooting and the docs,please let me know if you see anything I'm missing
`jest.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    projects: [
        {
            preset: "ts-jest",
            testEnvironment: "node",
            displayName: "client",
            roots: ["<rootDir>/client/src"],
            moduleDirectories: [
                "./",
                "./client",
                "./client/node_modules",
                "./client/src",
                "./node_modules",
                "/home/user/code/monorepo/",
                "/home/user/code/monorepo/client/",
                "/home/user/code/monorepo/client/src",
                "<rootDir>/client",
                "<rootDir>/client/node_modules",
                "<rootDir>/client/src",
                "<rootDir>/node_modules",
                "client",
                "client/node_modules",
                "client/src",
                "node_modules",
            ],
            modulePaths: [
                "./",
                "./client",
                "./client/src",
                "/home/user/code/monorepo/",
                "/home/user/code/monorepo/client/",
                "/home/user/code/monorepo/client/src",
                "<rootDir>/",
                "<rootDir>/client",
                "<rootDir>/client/src",
                "client/src",
                "src"
            ],
            testMatch: [
                "<rootDir>/client/**/*.spec.ts",
                "<rootDir>/client/**/*.spec.tsx",
                "<rootDir>/client/**/*.test.ts",
                "<rootDir>/client/**/*.test.tsx"
            ]
        },
        {
            preset: "ts-jest",
            testEnvironment: "node",
            setupFiles: ["dotenv/config"],
            displayName: "server",
            roots: ["<rootDir>/server/src/"]
        }
    ]
};
```

as you can see I really put of all the options I could think of as the paths, from absolute to relative to relative to `<rootDir>`, but still getting
`Cannot find module 'app' or its corresponding type declarations.` when importing `import { app } from "app"`.

Would love any help!